# Issue Enqueueing Wordpress style.css

Tags: php, css

I'm beginning the frustrating process of migrating an existing site over to a wordpress theme and have run into trouble immediately. For some reason that I can't pinpoint, my style.css theme is not being properly placed in my site's head after enqueuing (my site has no errors, the script just doesn't appear when I inspect using dev tools). I am attempting to enqueue the file in my functions.php like so...

```
<?php
    function add_fitnessfifteen_styles() {
            wp_enqueue_style( 'style', get_stylesheet_uri()); //enqueue style.css
    }
    add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'add_fitnessfifteen_styles' );
?>
```

I've been stuck on this seemingly simple issue for a couple of hours and figured I should turn to the experts. Somebody please make my day!

Answer (score 1):

My issue simply came as a result of not knowing that wp_head() needed to be included in header.php for the enqueued scripts to actually load on the site.